# Why is ROW_NUMBER() not recognized in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Why is `ROW_NUMBER()` not recognized as a function name in SQL Server 2008?

I try this

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() AS Row, Lname
FROM MEN
GO
```

and I get this error:

> Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 1
>   'ROW_NUMBER' is not a recognized
>   function name.

Comment: @Gold: did you ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You appear to be using the wrong syntax. Here is an example using the AdventureWorks database.

```
select 
    row_number() over(order by Name),   
    Name
from HumanResources.Department
```

Comment: The error would be "Incorrect syntax near 'ROW_NUMBER', expected 'OVER'", just tested on SQL 2005.

Comment: gbn is correct: the err message is *different* when the ROW_NUMBER function is called without an OVER clause. The exception indicates that the server isn't the correct version.

Answer (score 10):

Extending the other 2 answers...

I've tried the exact same command on SQL 2005 with 2 databases.

For both compatibility levels 80 and 90, the error is:

```
Msg 1035, Level 15, State 10, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'ROW_NUMBER', expected 'OVER'.
```

I can only generate this error on a SQL 2000 box:

```
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 2
'ROW_NUMBER' is not a recognized function name.
```

What does `SELECT @@version` say? I'd make 100% sure that you are on the version you expect...

My other thought is compat level 65 which [can't be set explicitly in SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx) and above it seems. And I don't have any legacy databases lying around to test.

Answer (score 4):

Check your database compatibility; ensure that it's set to 90 or higher.

It appears there are at least 2 things that are off the mark here.

- The syntax in your question is incorrect, but wouldn't be producing the unrecognized function error.
- SQL 2005 and 2008 do support the `ROW_NUMBER OVER()` keywords/command. Perhaps are you using SQL 2008 Management Studio to connect to a SQL 2000 machine? Double check with `SELECT @@Version` that your DB is indeed a SQL 2008 DB.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SSMS that says SQL Sever 2008, doesn't necessarily mean that you're connect to the respective DB.  Using @@version to check the version of the DB you're connected to because SQL 2005 uses : [ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ColName)]